# Firefox makes bogus call when a video tag is present

Tags: html, firefox, video, html5-video, firebug

I have a weird problem with firefox only.

To put it simply, I have an html (jsp) page with a `<video>` tag in it.

If I monitor how the page is loading with firebug, I can see that, at the end of the loading, a request is made to the "base href" of my page.
I have a base href tag like this : `<base href="http://localhost:8080/CHU/"  />` and the call is "GET /CHU/" (see screenshot below)

I can see the video being loaded and be ready to play before that bogus call happens!

If I remove everything in the video tag, like this :`<video></video>` the bogus call still happens.

For some reason this call will update the session and mess up with other stuff. So I have to prevent that to happen.

Any ideas?

Regards,
Michel

PS: works fine with chrome and IE

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Does it happen on a clean profile without Firebug? (you can use e.g. Fiddler or Wireshark to monitor the traffic).

Comment: Well if I disable Firebug, I can see the trace in my server log that a call is made.

Comment: Can you install Nightly build or Beta of Firefox and launch it in a new profile (`firefox -p --no-remote`) to verify it's the same? Could be a browser bug.

Comment: Can't do that. But I tried with a nearly empty page, the bug doesn't happen. So something must be interfering :-/

Answer (score 2):

I have a site that shows a very similar behaviour. I use jwplayer 6.5, Ff 22 and disabled the flash add in. A video tag is created, then an error is thrown. A trace on the net shows a call to the root of the site (base). It looks as if the video play were attempted with an empty source. The longtail guys claim it's not their script causing this, and I tend to believe them. It's only their handler that catches the error. So I believe I  indeed seeing the same symptom. Funny thing is: it only happens if the page was generated by Typo3. A static copy of the site with the same scripts does not show this. Tricky. If I find anything, I'll let you know. Might solve your issue as well.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I still haven't found any solution yet. I've just made a very uggly temporary workaround for this case.

Answer (score 0):

If have exactly the same problem using latest firefox, html5-video and base-href.

http://jsfiddle.net/38h8b/6/

```
<base href="http://jsfiddle.net/38h8b">
<video width="320" height="180" src="http://media.sublimevideo.net/vpa/ms_360p.mp4" autoplay="true"></video>
```